# Maven não funciona com proxy

Tags: maven, cmd

mvn archetype:generate -DartifactId="produtos" -DgroupId="br.com.alura.maven" -DinteractiveMode="false" -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype-quickstart"

quando eu tento executar esse trecho de código o maven não consegue fazer o download dos plugins, ele fica tentando buscar várias versões, mas não consegue fazer o download de nenhuma.

o meu cmd é bloqueado pelo proxy, não consigo baixar bibliotecas de python, nem nada que necessite de internet.
já experimentei mudar o proxy para algum estrangeiro, mas ainda assim não consegui fazer o download de nada do maven.

(o computador fica em um ambiente escolar, por isso o proxy)

Answer (score 0):

A única forma de se utilizar Maven com proxy é configurando seu `settings.xml` de acordo, como por exemplo:

```
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

Você pode conferir a documentação [aqui](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) e [aqui](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)